# How to discuss strategically about my weakest skills to find a suitable position?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, skills

During the interview, I found out the company is expanding and there are more than one position available complying with the job description I applied for, but with different duties.
I am invited to a 2nd interview where, according to the HR, we will discuss about a proper allocation of my profile among those available positions (the HR revealed they had problems in the past for having wrongly assigned the roles to the selected candidates).

Well, I guess that such discussion would be convenient also for me, so that we can find together a suitable assignment, but I would like to know how I can cleverly expose my weakest skills to support the elaboration but without any consequent drop of interest in my profile.

Example: possibly there will be a position as software development and another one as software verification engineer.
I like very much the software development workflow especially if compliant with standards, but I am not a skilled programmer and then I am afraid I would fail technical evaluations in that sense. I think rather to be quite skilled with the verification. How can I expose my lack of competence without losing interest on my profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think about it as a weakness but as a "least developed skill". There are a lot of skills I haven't used for some time. There are few I gained during "do and learn" process but I have no formal training or education.

That gives you opportunity to be proactive. Tell "XXX is not my forte as I've doing mostly YYY does the company could provide some training, boot camps etc.?". That show that in Dunning–Kruger scale you are past "I know everything". You know enough to be able to say you would need some help while showing you want to learn and be better.

Expect some leeway, you can't be 100% fit because that would mean your current role is exactly the same OR that in current role you were doing more that are not needed in future position (which is a loss for company). It should be well known that every new hire (even in internal) need time to learn new things. Recognize what they need to learn and what they don't need to know.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to know how I can cleverly expose my weakest skills

This seems backward. By focusing on your weaknesses, directly or indirectly, you run the risk of seeming unqualified or incompetent. In an interview, you want to be in a confident state of mind.

> I think rather to be quite skilled with the verification

If you prefer the verification engineer and think you would be a good fit, then steer the conversation toward your strengths in this area, and convince them you're the one they should choose.

Even if you're not a senior programmer, just having some experience in software development can be a plus. So rather than say you are not skilled, emphasize the experience you do have, and how it's an advantage.

Comment: The thing is that I don't prefer the verif. role, even as developer I can give a broad contribution. I have been working as sw developer and for a bit also coding, but I am not a very experienced programmer (I know only the basis to accomplish my tasks so far, that's it). But I just want to avoid a direct face up with coding during the interview.

Comment: It's kind of hard to be a SW developer, interview for a SW developer position, but somehow convince them not to bring up coding. Why are you going through the interview? If you tell them you're not very good at coding, what reason would they have to hire you?